# How to create multiway tables based on factors?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, presentation

I've been trying to create multiway tables with results, based on factor data.

My data looks like:

```
Trial    Room    Mechanism    Result
A        1       Straight     0,5
A        1       Bendy        0,2
A        2       Straight     0.7
A        2       Bendy        0.3
B        1       Straight     0.6
B        1       Bendy        0.2
B        2       Straight     0.6
B        2       Bendy        0.2
```

With in reality about 6 factors with multiple levels and one column of results.

The result i'm looking for is like this:

```
           Room 1      Room 2   
           A    B      A     B   
Straight  0.5   0.6    0.7   0.6
Bendy     0.2   0.2    0.3   0.2
```

Is there a function or a package that does this?

All the search results have yielded code to make multiway frequency tables from factors like with data.table() or count(). This is not what I am looking for.  Maybe I'm using the wrong key words or maybe there is much more information on that issue.

Doing this manipulation by hand is an option but not preferred. And besides I'm not the first person needing to do this so I know there is a way!

Comment: Maybe:  `library(reshape) ; cast(df, Mechanism ~ Trial + Room ,value = 'Result')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, where `reshape()` is used to re-format your data frame

```
df <- df[with(df,order(Room,Trial)),]
dfout <- reshape(within(df,RT <- apply(df[1:2],1,paste0,collapse = ""))[-(1:2)],
                 idvar = "Mechanism",
                 timevar = "RT",
                 direction = "wide")
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Mechanism Result.A1 Result.B1 Result.A2 Result.B2
1  Straight       0.5       0.6       0.7       0.6
2     Bendy       0.2       0.2       0.3       0.2
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Trial = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B"
), Room = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Mechanism = c("Straight", 
"Bendy", "Straight", "Bendy", "Straight", "Bendy", "Straight", 
"Bendy"), Result = c(0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Could not find an appropriate dupe so here is how you spread and re-order your columns. The trick is to assign both `Room` and `Trial` variables as your output columns. This is made particularly easy with `tidyr`'s new set of functions, `pivot_wider/pivot_longer`. After you spread, a simple regex can help you order the column to the format you need, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 pivot_wider(id_cols = Mechanism, names_from = c(Room, Trial), values_from = Result) %>% 
 select(1, order(sub('_.*', '', names(.))))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
>   Mechanism `1_A` `1_B` `2_A` `2_B`
>   <fct>     <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
> 1 Straight  0,5   0.6   0.7   0.6  
> 2 Bendy     0,2   0.2   0.3   0.2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For completion here is `data.table` version with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Mechanism~paste0('Room', Room) + Trial, value.var = 'Result')

#   Mechanism Room1_A Room1_B Room2_A Room2_B
#1:     Bendy     0,2     0.2     0.3     0.2
#2:  Straight     0,5     0.6     0.7     0.6
```